# Почему я получаю null при обращении к переменной другого класса?

Tags: java, android

Я новичок. Пишу в Android Studio.
В этом классе я выбираю дату и сохраняю её в переменную String date, после чего вызываю DisplayList

```
public class DatePickerClass extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

String date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showDatePicker();
}

public void showDatePicker () {
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this,
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yy");
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,dayOfMonth);
    date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplayList.class));
}
```

Но здесь переменная date почему то null

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_list);

    DatePickerClass datePickerClass = new DatePickerClass();
    System.out.println("The date is: "+datePickerClass.date);
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Жизненным циклом активности управляет операционная система, их нельзя создавать с помощью оператора `new`.

Comment: Оператор `new` создаёт новый объект, то есть совсем другой - в нём не может быть значений, которые вы записали в предыдущем. В случае с активностями нужно передавать через экстра данные в `Intent`. Для примера можете почитать этот урок: [Урок 28. Extras - передаем данные с помощью Intent](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. В теории я понимаю о чём вы. Но как на практике мне получить date из другого класса? Можно на словах объяснить, не обязательно готовый код.. Два дня голову ломаю уже((

Comment: @FornarySind с помощью [интентов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent). Крайне рекомендую почитать учебник вместо того, чтобы блуждать в темноте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `new` создаёт новый объект, то есть совсем другой - в нём не может быть значений, которые вы записали в предыдущем.
В случае с активностями нужно передавать через экстра данные в `Intent`.

```
public class DatePickerClass extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

String date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showDatePicker();
}

public void showDatePicker () {
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this,
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    datePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yy");
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,dayOfMonth);
    date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayList.class);
    // добавляем в интент данные
    intent.putExtra("date_key", date)
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

В новой активности получаем:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_list);
    // получаем интент, которым запущена активность
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // забираем свои данные
    System.out.println("The date is: "+ intent.getStringExtra("date_key"));
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я чувствовал, что надо с интентом передать дату. Но как это сделать не знал.